# Backbone router - set a static part in url

Tags: url, backbone.js, static, routes, set

I'm writing an app using Backbone.js. I want user to log in and to create this route:

```
 www.example.com/#username
```

And when she navigates through the app I want the url to look like this:

```
www.exmaple.com/#username/newroute
```

The problem is that I don't know the user name in advance, therefore I cannon add it to the routes when I start Backbone. I've tried passing a variable to the router like this:

```
routes: {
    myVariableWithName : "route"
}
```

but this variable cannot be passed in any way I can think of.

So I've tried different solution. When user did log in, I would get his username and use router.navigate(userName) to set it up. And then every link I would create in html would have this name like this:

```
 <a href="#username/route/"></a>
 routes: {
       'route/' : 'route'
 }
```

This does not work when using this:

```
 routes: {
       'route/:id' : 'route'
 }
```

So my question to you is, how should I do it?

Comment: adding a route to `:id/newroute` should work, could some thing else wrong in other part of the code, can you put all your router code in jsfiddle and provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your app and router set up properly, this should work:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    'users/:id' : 'routeUser'    
  },
  routeUser: function(id) {
    // performs action
  }
});
```

If this doesn't work, I think you'll need to post more code to get help as this isn't enough to go off of.